# Regular expression for 6 digit number with optional 2 decimal digits

Tags: regex, stringtokenizer

I need a regular expression for 6 digit number with optional 2 decimal digit
**Allowed values:**

```
    .1  .11  0.11  10. 10.1   10.12  00.00  0.0  00.00

   123456 12345 1234 123 12 1 0 0. 123. 123.55 123456.
```

Comment: Is it 6 digits maximum? Is `123456.78` allowed?

Answer (score 13):

Regex should be: `^\d{0,6}(\.\d{0,2})?$`(It passed all of your samples)

Update:

To avoid empty string and single dot, regex is `^(?!\.?$)\d{0,6}(\.\d{0,2})?$`. The expression adds a negative lookahead `?!\.?$`, which excludes 0 or 1 dot.

I added a unit test on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzheng/FXzRe/).

Comment: Matches the empty string and `.`. Also matches `123456.78` - should it?

Comment: I updated my answer to exclude empty string and single dot. But 123456.78 seems ok for "6 digit number with optional ..." means 6 digits are maximal BEFORE the decimal.

Comment: +1 for unit test. Nice work.

Answer (score 5):

Let's break it into four regexes. At least one of these four must match.

```
# decimal, 1-2 digits
\.\d{1,2}

# 1-4 digits, optional decimal, 0-2 digits
\d{1,4}\.?\d{0,2}

# 5 digits, optional decimal, optional digit
\d{5}\.?\d?

# 6 digits, optional decimal
\d{6}\.?
```

Which can then be combined into a single regex with the [alternation operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (`|`):

```
(\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,4}\.?\d{0,2}|\d{5}\.?\d?|\d{6}\.?)
```

Then add a caret (`^`) and stick (`$`) to [match the beginning and end of the string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

```
^(\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,4}\.?\d{0,2}|\d{5}\.?\d?|\d{6}\.?)$
```

This doesn't scale very well (e.g. if you wanted to match 100 digits with up to 20 after the decimal point) but it works and it's relatively easy to understand.

If you don't have to use a regex, there are easier ways to solve this problem. :)

Comment: This allows empty string and a single dot.

Comment: @Hui Thanks, fixed. Now each case requires at least one digit.

Comment: now your solution passed my unit test:)

Answer (score 2):

This r.e. is matching all your examples, and does not accept more than 6 digits or 2 decimals.

```
^\d{0,5}(\d\.\d?|\.\d)?\d?$
```

Comment: this allows "." also but i don't want only dot as i need value

Comment: changed to reflect your point

Comment: Matches the empty string and `123456.78` - should it?

Answer (score 0):

Quick java example for validating string with max length as 10
i.e. 9 digits with max 3 decimal
NOTE: why 9 digits instead of 10 digits? because the decimal point also count as a character

```
package com.baji.regex;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

/*
 * @author: Baji Shaik
 * Quick java example for validating string with max length as 10
 * i.e. 9 digits with max 3 decimal
 * NOTE: why 9 digits instead of 10 digits? because the decimal point also count as a character
*/
public class CheckNumber {


  @Test
  public void testSimpleTrue() {
    String s= "12345678.1";
    assertTrue(Validate10DigitsWithMax3DecimalsNumber(s));
    s= "1234567.12";
    assertTrue(Validate10DigitsWithMax3DecimalsNumber(s));
    s = "123456.123";
    assertTrue(Validate10DigitsWithMax3DecimalsNumber(s));
    s = "123456789";
    assertTrue(Validate10DigitsWithMax3DecimalsNumber(s));

    s = "1234567891";
    assertTrue(Validate10DigitsWithMax3DecimalsNumber(s));
    s = ".123";
    assertTrue(Validate10DigitsWithMax3DecimalsNumber(s));

    s = "000000.123";
    assertTrue(Validate10DigitsWithMax3DecimalsNumber(s));

  }


  public static boolean Validate10DigitsWithMax3DecimalsNumber(String value){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\.\\d{1,3}|\\d{1,6}\\.\\d{1,3}|\\d{1,7}\\.\\d{1,2}|\\d{1,8}\\.\\d{1}|\\d{1,10})$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
    if (matcher.find()){
      return true; 
    } 
    return false; 
  }

}
```